# How does controller work in web2py?

Tags: python, web2py

I have a question about how controllers and [Form](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07#FORM) work in web2py.
Consider next controller function (from we2py book):

```
def display_form():
form=FORM('Your name:',
          INPUT(_name='name', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
          INPUT(_type='submit'))
if form.accepts(request,session):
    response.flash = 'form accepted'
elif form.errors:
    response.flash = 'form has errors'
else:
    response.flash = 'please fill the form'
return dict(form=form)
```

This function two goals: first is to return a form and second is to tell what to do on submission button.
I cannot understand how it is possible. Is it called two times? first time when view need to know what is form and second time when submit button is pressed?
Intuitively this piece:

```
if form.accepts(request,session):
    response.flash = 'form accepted'
elif form.errors:
    response.flash = 'form has errors'
else:
    response.flash = 'please fill the form'
```

should be in some different function which is responsible for post processing.

How does it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the function is called twice. When the URL for that function is called without posting any form values, the `form.accepts()` function fails (i.e., returns False) because no data have been submitted. In that case, all that is returned is a new blank form. When the user ultimately submits the form, the form values are posted to the same function. In that case, `form.accepts()` finds the posted form data in `request.post_vars`. It then validates the data, and if validation passes, it returns True and `response.flash` is set to 'form accepted'.

This is referred to as a postback or self-submission. For more, see [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03#Postbacks).

Comment: New to web2py, I am still partly puzzled. When user submits the form, the action shall execute from the beginning. The first line of the action line is:

`form=FORM(...)`

Looking from a programming language point of view, doesn't this mean that in this 2nd call to action, form is reference to a new "form" object returned by the web2py's FORM()?

Comment: Yes, it is a new FORM object, but it has the same structure as the original form, which is all that is needed to handle the processing.

Comment: Thank you Anthony. It is still not crystal clear to me, but for the moment, I can live with that.